# If almost all primes of $K$ that are totally split in $M$ are totally split in $L$, then $L \subset M$.

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, extension-field, alternative-proof

In Cox's book *Primes of the form $x^2+ny^2$*, we have the following proposition 8.20.

> Let $K$ be a number field, $L,M$ be finite extensions of $K$ such that $M/K$ is Galois.
>   Then
>   $$L \subset M \\\iff\\ \text{all but finitely many of the primes of $K$  that are totally split in $M$ are also totally split in $L$.}$$

The direction $\implies$ is not difficult. However, the direction $\Longleftarrow$ is proved using Čebotarev theorem. **Is there a way to prove this proposition without using this theorem (nor class field theory)?**

Let's assume first that $L/K$ is Galois. I tried to show that $LM=M$ by looking at the degree $[LM:M]=efr$ where I take a prime of $LM$ above a prime of $M$... I know that "totally split in $L$ and in $M$" implies "totally split in $LM$".
But I'm stuck there.

Thank you!

Comment: "Totally ramified in $ L $ and $ M $ impies totally ramified in $ LM $" is an incorrect statement. For a counterexample, take $ L = \mathbf Q(\sqrt{3}) $, $ M = \mathbf Q(\sqrt{7}) $, $ K = \mathbf Q $. Then, $ 2 $ is totally ramified in both $ L $ and $ M $, but not totally ramified in $ LM $.

Comment: @Starfall : thank you. I wanted to say totally split.

Comment: This was proved by Kronecker and Bauer long before class field theory. I do not know a proof without zeta functions, however,

Comment: @franzlemmermeyer : do you have at least a reference for such a proof (avoiding class field theory)?. Zeta functions are OK for me.

Comment: [This](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/200677) is related. Possibly you are talking about [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/218759) (which is used in the proof of 2.6 [here](http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/gradnumthy/cfthistory.pdf)).

Comment: Exactly. Kronecker's claims were worked out by Frobenius, and the Frobenius density theorem is sufficient for proving Bauer's result. And by the way, the density theorems of Frobenius and Chebotarev do not require class field theory; you may use class field theory, however, to make the proof of Chebotarev's theorem as easy as the one by Frobenius.

Comment: @franzlemmermeyer : do you have a reference that proves Cebotarev theorem without class field theory? I would be interested if so. (Or what would be the easiest proofs of Cebotarev or Frobenius theorems according to you?)

Comment: Try one of Ribenboim's books on algebraic number theory. Or see my notes http://www.fen.bilkent.edu.tr/~franz/cft/cfb.pdf  starting on p. 98.

Comment: In short, If you remove the prime ideals with $N(\mathfrak{p})$ prime, you get an Euler product converging for $Re(s) > 1/2$, and $\zeta_F(s)$ has a pole of order $1$ at $s=1$, so the polar density has to be $1/[k:K]$. together with $\Spl(M/K) \cap \Spl(L/K) = \Spl(LM/K)$ you get the result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to [Franz Lemmermeyer](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/23365/franz-lemmermeyer)'s comments above, I am able to provide an answer.
I will however assume that $L/K$ is Galois. The direction $\implies$ is not really difficult. The converse is more interesting.

Let's introduce the following definition:

> **Definition.** If $T$ is a set of prime ideals of a number field $K$ and if $\zeta_{T,K}^n$ has a pole of order $m$ at $s=1$ where
>   $$\zeta_{K,T}(s):=\prod\limits_{p \in T} \dfrac{1}{1-N(p)^{-s}},$$ then
>   $$d(T)=m/n$$ is called the *polar density* of $T$.

Here $N(p) = |O_K/p|$ is the absolute norm of $p$.

We can check the following properties:

— The polar density is additive : if $T$ and $T'$ are two disjoint sets of primes of $K$, then
$$d(T \sqcup T') = d(T)+d(T')$$

– The polar density is monotonic : if $T \subset T'$ then
$$d(T) \leq d(T')$$

– A finite set of primes of $K$ has density $0$, and the set of all prime ideals of $K$ has density $1$.

$\newcommand\Spl{\mathrm{Spl}}$
The main claim is the following:

> **Theorem:** The set $\Spl(L/K)$ of prime ideals of $K$ that are totally split in $L$ has polar density $1/[L:K]$.

Then the inclusion $L \subset M$ follows from $\Spl(M/K) \setminus T \subset \Spl(L/K)$, where $T$ is a finite set of primes of $K$. Indeed, we want to show $LM=M$, i.e. $[M:K]=[LM:K]$. 
Since $\Spl(M/K) \cap \Spl(L/K) = \Spl(LM/K)$, we get
$$\Spl(M/K) \setminus T \subset \Spl(LM/K)  \subset \Spl(M/K)$$
Then
$d(\Spl(M/K))=d(\Spl(M/K) \setminus T ) + d(T) = d(\Spl(M/K) \setminus T )$, since $T$ is finite.
Therefore, we obtain
$$d(\Spl(M/K))=d(\Spl(M/K) \setminus T ) \leq d(\Spl(LM/K)) \leq d(\Spl(M/K))$$
whence
$$\dfrac{1}{[LM:K]} =  d(\Spl(LM/K)) = d(\Spl(M/K)) = \dfrac{1}{[M:K]},$$
which shows $[M:K]=[LM:K]$ as desired.

---

Let's prove the theorem.

> **Proof.**
>   $\newcommand\Spec{\mathrm{Spec}}$

**Step 1.** Let $S=\Spl(L/K)$ and $T = \{q \in \Spec(\mathcal{O}_L) \mid q \cap K \in S\}$.
We claim that $$\zeta_{L,T}(s) = \zeta_{K,S}(s)^{[L:K]}.$$
(in the next steps, we will show that $\zeta_{L,T}$ has a pole of order $1$ at $s=1$).

Indeed, if $p \in S$, then $pO_L = \mathfrak{q}_1 \cdots \mathfrak{q}_{[L:K]}$ with
$N_{L/\mathbb{Q}}(\mathfrak{q}_i) = N_{K/\Bbb Q}(p)$ and $\mathfrak{q}_i \in T$.
Therefore
$$ \zeta_{L,T}(s) = 
\prod\limits_{\mathfrak{q} \in T} (1-N(\mathfrak{q})^{-s})^{-1} =
\prod\limits_{p \in S} \prod\limits_{\mathfrak{q} \mid p} 
 (1-N_{L/\mathbb{Q}}(\mathfrak{q})^{-s})^{-1} =
 \prod\limits_{p \in S}
 (1-N(p)^{-s})^{-[L:K]} = 
\zeta_{K,S}(s)^{[L:K]} $$

**Step 2.** We know that $T$ contains
$$Q := \{\mathfrak{q} \in \Spec(\mathcal{O}_L) \mid N(\mathfrak{q}) \text{ is prime in } \mathbb{Z}  \;\text{ and }\; 
\mathfrak{q} \cap K \text{ is unramified in } L\}$$
so that writing 
$\Spec(\mathcal{O}_L) = T \sqcup T^c$, where $T^c$ is the  complement of $T$ in $\Spec(\mathcal{O}_L)$ yields
$T^c \subset Q^c =  P \cup  R$
where $$P:=\{\mathfrak{q} \in \Spec(\mathcal{O}_L) \mid 
N(\mathfrak{q}) \text{ is not prime in } \mathbb{Z} \}$$ and $$R:=\{\mathfrak{q} \in \Spec(\mathcal{O}_L) \mid 
\mathfrak{q} \cap K \text{ is ramified in } L \}.$$
Notice that $R$ is finite, so that $d(R)=0$.

**Step 3.** We show that $d(P)=0$.
If $\mathfrak{q} \in P$, then $N_{L/\mathbb{Q}}(\mathfrak{q}) = p^f$ for some prime $p \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $f \geq 2$.

Conversely, given a prime $p \in \mathbb{Z}$, there are at most $[L:\Bbb Q]$ primes of $L$ above $p$.

Then
$$\zeta_{L,P}(s) = 
\prod\limits_{\mathfrak{q} \in P} (1-N(\mathfrak{q})^{-s})^{-1} =
\prod\limits_{\substack{p \in \mathbb{Z} \\ p \text{ prime }}} 
\prod\limits_{i=1}^{[L:\mathbb{Q}]} 
g_i(p;s)=
\prod\limits_{i=1}^{[L:\mathbb{Q}]} 
\underbrace{\prod\limits_{\substack{p \in \mathbb{Z} \\ p \text{ prime }}} 
g_i(p;s)}_{=: g_i(s)}
$$
where $p\mathcal{O}_L = \mathfrak{q}_1^{e_1} \cdots \mathfrak{q}_{r(p)}^{e_{r(p)}}$ and$$g_i(p;s):=
\begin{cases}
(1-p^{-f(\mathfrak{q}_i/p)s})^{-1} & 
    \text{if }\; i \leq r(p) \leq [L:\mathbb{Q}]   \;\text{ and }\;   f(\mathfrak{q}_i/p) \geq 2\\
1    & \text{else.}
\end{cases}$$

But for all $i$, we have
$$g_i(1) = \prod\limits_{\substack{p \in \mathbb{Z} \\ p \text{ prime }}} 
g_i(p;1) \leq \prod\limits_{\substack{p \in \mathbb{Z} \\ p \text{ prime }}}  (1-p^{-2})^{-1}
= \zeta(2) < \infty$$

Therefore $g_i$ is holomorphic at $s=1$and so is $\zeta_{L,P} = \prod_{i=1}^{[L:\mathbb{Q}]} g_i$.

Therefore $d(P)=0/1=0$.

**Step 4.** Finally, $d(T^c) = 0$ and by monotonicity,
$d(T)=1$, which means that $\zeta_{L,T}$ has a pole of order $1$ at $s=1$. Since $\zeta_{L,T}(s) = \zeta_{K,S}(s)^{[L:K]}$, we can write $d(S)=\dfrac{1}{[L:K]}$, as desired.
$\hspace{17cm}\blacksquare$

All these ideas can be found in Milne, Class field theory, chap. VI, §3.